# What causes chmod to not work on an ssh file in OSX?

Tags: macos, ssh, permission, filesystem

I am trying to mount private keys from USB stick. OSx does not allow me to change their permissions, why? How can I change them? In other words, how can I add private keys from random USB stick to ssh-agent?

[image]

Comment: Can you run an ls -l on school to show it's current perms? In addition to the file itself, SSH gets grumpy if the permissions on the directory they're in are open. Make sure that .ssh has restrictive perms, I think 600 is good, from memory.

Comment: ...err execute permission is too much. Read permission is enough i.e. 400. You can see the current perms in the picture i.e. 777 -- OSx automounts the USB to everyone apparently in the system, now trying to find a way to do it without copying files to the disk. Please, see my answer for a way to solve it, not the safest method but works.

Comment: You need execute on a directory to see what it's contents are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll bet your USB stick is formatted as FAT, FAT32 or NTFS. OS X's Unix-style permissions are not compatible with FAT and FAT32 filesystems. Additionally, by default, OS X cannot write to NTFS volumes. Make sure the USB stick is formatted as HFS+.

And finally, the file containing the SSH private key **must** have permissions set to `600` and the folder containing the file **must** have permissions set to `700`

Comment: Why 600 and not 400? They need just read -access, where do you need write access for files? Any idea how can I create OS X -style fs with non-mac -devices? This is going be a problem if I use many systems.

Comment: You can try 400 instead of 600. I suggested 600 because that's what I have on my system.  ...  To make your USB stick a "Mac device" just format it using Disk Utility.app.

Comment: If 400 you cannot edit it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem with

```
$ cp /Volumes/disk/.ssh ~
$ eval `ssh-agent`
$ chmod 400 ~/.ssh/*
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/school
```

but this does not solve the original prob i.e. without copying ssh-keys to computer to add keys to the daemon

Comment: This worked for me: sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Answer (score 2):

As late as OS X 10.13/High Sierra, you can add an `/etc/fstab` file owned by root, even if it doesn't exist on your system, with the following content:

```
LABEL=PRIVATE none msdos -u=501,-m=700
```

This assumes that your user ID is 501 (check with `ls -n ~`) and that the label of your mounted FAT/ExFAT drive is `PRIVATE`.  I use this for mounting VeraCrypt volume-files with ssh keys (FAT and ExFAT) that I share b/w OS X and Linux. Should work with USB drives as well, but haven't tried exactly that.